# How to run webviews in multiple threads

Tags: android, webview

My assigment says to create a simple web browser where webpage is saved in a card and later on you can retrieve it.

**Each card/webpage need to run on it's own thread.**

I've already setted up webview and `myWebViewClient` to load links, and a 2nd activity where i display and can add new webpages. Selecting ListView item is calling `loadUrl(url)` in `MainActivity` on a `WebView`, but that's not the desireable outcome, I need to run webview in a thread, put it away on a stack, and later resume it's task somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Activity for each WebView and save his task ID in a List. If the ID doesn't exists on the stack you create a new one WebView Activity and put it on the stack,  otherwise you push the existent WebView Activity from stack and resume this activity.

Launch WebView Activities using flags: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK

Inside these activities call getTaskId() and make the ID available to your main activity. When you want to resume an activity, do the following:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.moveTaskToFront(taskId, 0);
```

Requires permission permission `android.Manifest.permission.REORDER_TASKS`

this work if memory management doesn't destroy your activity, in this case the OnCreate method will call.

Comment: Thanks ! I achieved the exact behaviour that i wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can not directly run the webview in the background as In Android, all the views needs to be run on UI thread.

For your task, you can do one thing, load the html data in bacground and then set that html response to webview in onPost method of Asyntask

Comment: You can create and call all methods of `WebView` in a non-UI thread given that thread has a looper